# How to troubleshoot DNS with systemd-resolved?

Tags: systemd, dns, troubleshooting

How would you go about finding the DNS servers used by `systemd-resolved`, for troubleshooting purposes?

Generally I can use `dig` and test the DNS servers shown in `/etc/resolv.conf`.  (Or windows - `ipconfig /all` + `nslookup`).  But that approach doesn't work when resolv.conf just points to a local resolver daemon on a loopback address.  What method is used under systemd-resolved, to show the DNS servers it uses?

---

(`unbound` has config files I could look into.  `dnsmasq` does too, though I'm not sure if servers can be added dynamically without a config file.  Even NetworkManager, now has `nmcli`, and I see you can query `nmcli d show wlan0` to show the DNS configuration for an interface.)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use `resolvectl status` (`systemd-resolve --status` when using systemd version earlier than [239](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS?utm_source=anzwix#L87)) to show your [global and per-link DNS settings](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/resolvectl.html#status%20%5BLINK%E2%80%A6%5D).

Comment: Unfortunately, in my ubuntu 16.04.6 there is no resolvectl and the systemd-resolve command has no "--status" option.

Comment: There is also `resolvectl query` but unfortunately it doesn't  have verbose option.

Comment: This feature can be up-voted there: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/17330

Comment: `resolvectl` without any parameter seems to provide the same output.

Answer (score 131):

Very helpful for troubleshooting is also:

```
journalctl -u systemd-resolved -f
```

There you can see what `systemd-resolved` is really doing.
In my case it was not contacting the DNS servers that were reported via `systemd-resolve --status` at all.
If it's doing weird things like that, then somtimes a restart via `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved` is a good idea.

**EDIT:**

In order to get more information from `resolved` you need to put

```
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

into the `override.conf` of `systemd-resolved` via

```
sudo systemctl edit systemd-resolved
```

Restart to take effect:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

**EDIT 2:**

Don't forget to revert this afterwards as @bmaupin and @Aminovic have helpfully pointed out in the comments.

```
sudo systemctl revert systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that after running `sudo systemctl edit systemd-resolved` it seems `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved` needs to be run in order for the new settings to be applied. Thanks!

Comment: After all these years without having to deal with windows, not much anyway, you get the "If it's doing weird things like that, then somtimes a restart via.." advice and you know you are back to where you started. Sigh.

Comment: It might also be helpful to add the command to undo this when you're done troubleshooting: `sudo systemctl revert systemd-resolved`

Comment: Do not forget to remove the debug mode after you finish! on my side, it was filling the server's disk

Comment: This is way easier to to run systemctl service-log-level systemd-resolved debug. Because non persistent

Answer (score 8):

### The `resolv.conf` file

The manual says:

> The resolver is a set of routines in the C library that provide access to the Internet Domain Name System (DNS). The resolver config file contains information that is read by the resolver routines the first time they are invoked by a process.
>
> If this file does not exist, only the name server on the local machine will be queried, and the search list contains the local domain name determined from the hostname.

### `systemd-resolved`

On Ubuntu 20.04, `systemd-resolved` is a local DNS server included with [`systemd`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/systemd) that acts as a stub resolver and it should automatically edit `/etc/resolv.conf` with the correct config.

On older versions you might need to manually symlink it with the following:

```
$ sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

By default, `systemd-resolved` configures a local DNS server listening at `127.0.0.53` on port `53` and you can run `lsof -i @127.0.0.53:53` to verify. Make sure you do not have any other service like `dnsmasq` listening to the same address and port.

Note that `127.0.0.53` is the loopback interface but you can have another DNS server listening on port 53 at another IP address on the loopback interface, like `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.0.2`.

If it does not work, try the following:

```
$ sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

This file contains DNS servers from DHCP leases but be aware that you will not benefit from the stub resolver caching feature.

### `dnsmasq` with `NetworkManager`

The [`dnsmasq`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/dnsmasq) lightweight caching DNS server accepts DNS queries and either answers them from a small, local, cache or forwards them to a real, recursive, DNS server.

This is very good to have a little DNS service to test local websites for a web development machine.

First, verify that `NetworkManager` manages your current interface (`wlp0s20f3` in my case):

```
$ nmcli dev
$ nmcli dev set wlp0s20f3 managed yes
```

Now you can enable the `NetworkManager` built-in `dnsmasq` resolver:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

You can now benefit from the flexibility of `NetworkManager` along `dnsmasq`, whose config is located in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d`:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/custom.conf
# Resolve all domains ending in .dev to 127.0.0.1
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
```

Do not forget to disable the system-wide `dnsmasq` service if present and apply your changes:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq.service && sudo systemctl disable dnsmasq.service
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

---

If for some reasons you prefer to have `dnsmasq` running separately, you must first prevent `NetworkManager` from overriding `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
dns=none
```

Now you must tell `dnsmasq` to get its upstream servers from somewhere other that `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
listen-address=127.0.0.53
resolv-file=/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
```

This file is generated by `NetworkManager` and also contains DNS servers from DHCP leases. Now configure `dnsmasq` for resolving:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Use local dnsmasq resolver
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Configure your own local DNS settings:

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/custom.conf
# Resolve all domains ending in .dev to 127.0.0.1
address=/.dev/127.0.0.1
```

Apply your new config:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service && sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
$ sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq.service
```

### `dnsmasq` with `systemd-networkd`

Unfortunately it is not as easy as with `NetworkManager` and this is due to the fact that `systemd-networkd` does not expose a file with DNS nameservers obtained from DHCP servers as this is managed by `systemd-resolved` instead.

This is also the case if you use the quite deprecated `ifupdown` package.

Open the `man` for `dhclient-script`:

```
$ man 8 dhclient-script
```

The **HOOKS** section says:

> When it starts, the client script first defines a shell function, `make_resolv_conf`, which is later used to create the `/etc/resolv.conf` file. To override the default behaviour, redefine this function in the enter hook script.

So if you still want to use `dnsmasq` along `systemd-networkd` you will need to redefine `make_resolv_conf` to create a `resolv-file` for `dnsmasq` so that it can get its upstream servers from your DHCP settings.

The [`resolvconf`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/resolvconf) package provides a wrapper interface around the different daemons involved in populating `/etc/resolv.conf` and you can use it to configure the `make_resolv_conf` behavior.

---

The same problem also happens if you need to obtain the IPv6 upstream servers from RDNSS in Router Advertisement messages (see [Neighbor Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol)) as this is also managed by `systemd-resolved`.

Try the following command from the [`ndisc6`](https://www.remlab.net/ndisc6/) package:

```
$ rdisc6 wlp0s20f3
```

You should see various information coming from your router, including your IPv6 address prefix and DNS servers. If you do not see anything, your router may not support it.

The `rdisc6` program implements the ICMPv6 Router Discovery in userland, using [`NETLINK_ROUTE`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/rtnetlink.7.en.html) sockets for which RDNSS support was added in Linux kernel 2.6.24. If you want to support older versions, you have no choices but to interact with the device driver at OSI Layer 2, using [`SOCK_RAW`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/packet.7.en.html) sockets.

Comment: Your two code blocks contain exactly the same commands. I think you intended them to be different.

Comment: @berndbausch the snippets are not the same if you look closely, one is for `stub-resolv.conf` and the other for `resolv.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

None of the answers here brought me any closer to a working `systemd-resolved`. One solution to all `systemd-resolved` problems is to remove it from the equation.

First disable it (as root):

```
service systemd-resolved stop
systemctl disable systemd-resolved
```

But that's not enough. Systemd will  re-enable it and start it right back up after a few minutes. So you must prevent that by removing `systemd-resolved` from your server entirely:

```
rm -f /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
```

I've never had problems from other parts of systemd as a result of doing this, but YMMV. Instead of removing it, you could rename it.

Finally, edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and put some name servers into it:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: I dump systemd-resolved too and all is well. I mask the service `systemctl mask systemd-resolved`. this  stops systemd from restarting the service. No need to do that now, but next time?

Comment: If the service is being restarted by something you can't find, there probably is a need to use `systemctl mask` instead. When you install an updated package, it will almost certainly recreate those files you deleted.

Comment: I had to look up what Poettering considers "mask" to mean: "This will link these unit files to /dev/null, making it impossible to start them. This is the stronger version of disable, since it prohibits all kinds of activation of the unit, including enablement and manual activation."