# How to configure systemd-resolved and systemd-networkd to use local DNS server for resolving local domains and remote DNS server for remote domains?

Tags: linux, systemd, dns, systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved

I'm connected to local area network with access to the Internet through gateway. There is DNS server in local network which is capable of resolving hostnames of computers from local network.

I would like to configure *systemd-resolved* and *systemd-networkd* so that lookup requests for local hostnames would be directed (routed) exclusively to local DNS server and lookup requests for all other hostnames would be directed exclusively to another, remote DNS server.

Let's assume I don't know where the configuration files are or whether I should add more files and require their path(s) to be specified in the answer.

Comment: Seems such a normal request.  I hope networkd lives for a very long time before Linux networking gets fiddled with again

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In the configuration file for local network interface (a file matching the name pattern `/etc/systemd/network/*.network`) we have to either specify we want to obtain local DNS server address from DHCP server using [`DHCP=` option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#DHCP=):

```
[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

or specify its address explicitly using [`DNS=` option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#DNS=):

```
[Network]
DNS=10.0.0.1
```

In addition we need to specify (in the same section) local domains using [`Domains=` option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#Domains=)

```
Domains=domainA.example domainB.example ~example
```

We specify local domains `domainA.example domainB.example` to get the following behavior (from *systemd-resolved.service, systemd-resolved* man page):

> Lookups for a hostname ending in one of the per-interface domains are
>   exclusively routed to the matching interfaces.

This way `hostX.domainA.example` will be resolved **exclusively** by our local DNS server.

We specify with `~example` that all domains ending in `example` are to be treated as route-only domains to get the following behavior (from description of [this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/b9fe94cad99968a58e169592d999306fd059eb14) commit) :

> DNS servers which have route-only domains should only be used for the
>   specified domains.

This way `hostY.on.the.internet` will be resolved **exclusively** by our global, remote DNS server.

**Note**

Ideally, when using DHCP protocol, local domain names should be obtained from DHCP server instead of being specified explicitly in configuration file of network interface above. See [`UseDomains=` option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#UseDomains=). However there are still outstanding issues with this feature – see [systemd-networkd DHCP search domains option](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8174) issue.

We need to specify remote DNS server as our global, system-wide DNS server. We can do this in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` file:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

Don't forget to reload configuration and to restart services:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

**Caution!**

Above guarantees apply only when names are being resolved by *systemd-resolved* – see [man page for *nss-resolve, libnss_resolve.so.2*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-resolve.html) and [man page for systemd-resolved.service, systemd-resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html).

See also:

- [Description of routing lookup requests in systemd related man pages is unclear](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8928)
- [How to troubleshoot DNS with systemd-resolved?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328131/5355)

References:

- [Man page for systemd-resolved.service, systemd-resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html)
- [Man page for resolved.conf, resolved.conf.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/resolved.conf.html)
- [Man page for systemd-network](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html)

Comment: Have you considered not using `.local` in this example? Certainly with avahi, this was supposed to be reserved for MDNS and misusing it was a big no-no. It would be clearer to me to use `example.com` or [.example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.example).

Comment: @sourcejedi For reference `.local` is defined as special domain in RFC 6762 – *Multicast DNS* in section [Multicast DNS Names](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762#section-3). Thanks, fixed.

Comment: The network configuration file must be named something that matches `/etc/systemd/network/*.network`.  The value of `*` doesn't appear to matter.  You use a `[Match]` section within each file to limit which network interface(s) it applies to.

Comment: @gps, moreover, without `[Match]` section, file seems to be ignored altogether

Comment: You *have* to configure the `[Match]` section somehow, otherwise you get something to the effect of:
```
/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network: No valid settings found in the [Match] section, ignoring file. To match all interfaces, add Name=* in the [Match] section.
```
@PiotrDobrogost
I would add that to my answer, if I were you.

Comment: Why is `Domains=domainA.example domainB.example ~example` needed - wouldn't `Domains=~example` provide the same?

Comment: @laur Yes, it would provide the same as long as routing of DNS queries is concerned. The reason why they are listed in addition to `~example` is explained in a note further in the answer. Strictly speaking (answering only the question as stated) local domains do not need to be listed in `Domains` directive. However without `UseDomains` directive working at the time (as explained in the note) I kind of treated listing local domains in `Domains` directive as the essential part of preferred DNS configuration as otherwise single-label hostnames wouldn't be resolved against these local domains.

Comment: If DHCP(v4/v6) servers provide information about DNS server IP(v4/6) addresses, and you **do not want to use** these for your *systemd*-managed network units / network interfaces, you have to explicitly exclude them under the [`[DHCPv4]`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.network.html#%5BDHCPv4%5D%20Section%20Options) and [`[DHCPv6]`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.network.html#%5BDHCPv6%5D%20Section%20Options) sections with [`UseDNS=false`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.network.html#UseDNS=).

Answer (score 7):

Just to expand on @piotrDobrogost 's excellent answer, don't forget to config `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to use `systemd-resolved` as a DNS resolution source.  Your `hosts` directive should look as follows for your particular use case:

***/etc/nsswitch.conf***

```
hosts:  files resolve dns
```

So if you limit the resolution to only those domains specified in the `Domains` directive in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` as Piotr details above, DNS should next be consulted in the order of name resolution sources specified `/etc/nsswitch.conf` when domains are **NOT** found in `Domains` directive:

The following link references the requirement to specify ***resolve*** in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` so `systemd-resolved` is consulted during name resolution:

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/940

SystemD documentation I've found to be dire.  I had to piece together an understanding from multiple links, including Piotr's answer above ;-)

Comment: When using [recommended](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#/etc/resolv.conf) mode of operation of _systemd-resolved_ where `/etc/resolve.conf` is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` file which in turn contains address of _systemd-resolve's_ DNS stub resolver there's no need to place `resolve` directive in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file as DNS requests will be directed (due to the standard `nss-dns` directive) to stub resolver which acts according to _systemd-resolved's_ rules.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost How could you control the order sources of DNS resolution are consulted without using `/etc/nsswitch.conf``?  In the specimen config above, `/etc/hosts` ("***files***") would be checked for static **IP:name** mappings and if none found, the systemd-resolved stub resolved would next be consulted.  I can't see how it would be possible to therefore stage sources of DNS resolution without using `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.  Am I missing a trick here?

Comment: I'm not saying `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is not needed. I'm saying that when one uses _systemd-resolved's_ stub DNS resolver then it's enough to have `dns` directive listed in `hosts:` line (presumably after `file` directive). There is no need for `resolve` directive there as it's the stub resolver that is the *entry point* to the _systemd-resolved's_ logic and not the `nss-resolve` plug-in module...

Comment: ... In other words you can *reach* _systemd-resolved's_ logic either through `resolve` directive ➟ _nss-resolve_ NSS plug-in module ➟ _systemd-resolved_ or through `dns` directive ➟ _nss-dns_ NSS plug-in module  ➟ _systemd-resolved's_' stub DNS resolver ➟ _systemd-resolved_

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I think I arrived at the `files` then `resolve` thingy in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` from the 2nd part of your question. Re-reading it, looks like you were just talking about checking the local cache for an **IP:name** mapping then reaching-out to a forwarder if not found.  I generally set `files` first DNS source of resolution to bypass DNS to allow me to test and not hit the production hosts- T

Comment: I don't blame you as the `resolve` directive was in the past the recommended way of using _systemd-resolved_ logic. As there were differences in the behavior when using `resolve` directive and when querying DNS server(s) listed in `/etc/resolv.conf` directly which lead to much confusion later the recommended way of using _systemd-resolved_ logic was changed to using stub DNS resolver. See for instance [nsswitch.conf doesn't specify 'resolve' to support systemd-resolved](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1769016).

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this because you have an connection configured with OpenVPN, you need to use https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved as per https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#The_update-systemd-resolved_custom_script

Specifically, once, you have the `update-systemd-resolved` script installed and active in your OpenVPN client config, you'll also add `dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE yourdomain.com` to the same client config.

You should see the following output from OpenVPN:

```
<14>Apr 22 16:10:31 update-systemd-resolved: Link 'tun0' coming up
<14>Apr 22 16:10:31 update-systemd-resolved: Adding DNS Routed Domain yourdomain.com
<14>Apr 22 16:10:31 update-systemd-resolved: Adding DNS Domain yourdomain.com
<14>Apr 22 16:10:31 update-systemd-resolved: Adding IPv4 DNS Server 192.168.XYZ.XYZ
<14>Apr 22 16:10:31 update-systemd-resolved: SetLinkDNS(640 1 2 4 192 168 XYZ XYZ)
<14>Apr 22 16:10:31 update-systemd-resolved: SetLinkDomains(640 2 yourdomain.com false yourdomain.com true)
```

And you can verify the DNS configuration with `resolvectl status`:

```
Link 3 (wlp0s....)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.XYZ.XYZ
         DNS Servers: 192.168.XYZ.XYZ
          DNS Domain: ~.
                      lan
Link 640 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.XYZ.XYZ
         DNS Servers: 192.168.XYZ.XYZ
          DNS Domain: ~yourdomain.com
```

Comment: really helpful indeed. once the openvpn has been setup this is a really simple addition. thanks