# do "search domain" in networkd configuration and LLMNR conflict?

Tags: dns, systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved

in [networkd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/systemd.network.5.html) man page, the search domains are used to handle single-label names:

***The domains without the prefix are called "search domains" and are first used as search suffixes for extending single-label host names (host names containing no dots) to become fully qualified domain names (FQDNs). If a single-label host name is resolved on this interface, each of the specified search domains are appended to it in turn, converting it into a fully qualified domain name, until one of them may be successfully resolved.***

***Both "search" and "routing-only" domains are used for routing of DNS queries: look-ups for host names ending in those domains (hence also single label names, if any "search domains" are listed), are routed to the DNS servers configured for this interface.***

I wonder if a single-label name lookup request is handled by LLMNR or by the specified dns severs or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single-label name is **only** handled by LLMNR, **if solved**.

If **not** solved, each of the [list of words in `Domains=`:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442599/265604)

```
Domains=domainA.example domainB.example ~example
```

is added at the end of the single-label and an attempt to resolve it is done. If it gets resolved at any trial, that is the end, if not resolved, try with the next word.

To resolve, [different `name resolution` resources might be used](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html): Avahi, resolved, LLMNR, or (usually at last) several DNS servers.