# Facing issue with systemd-resolved after update

Tags: networking, fedora, dns, systemd-resolved, host-name-resolution

I recently updated my system, but noticed that on reboot, systemd-resolved always fails. So I cannot access any websites even though I have internet connection.

I have included an error message that I'm getting (I could not find any other post mentioning this exact error either).

Is anyone facing the same problem or has a fix? I think it is an issue with DNS resolution and as temporary workaround I'm including a `nameserver` in `/etc/resolv.conf`. But since this is a temporary fix and I wanted to know if there's a way to fix `systemd-resolved` since it worked fine before updating the system.

Below is version of systemd

```bash
➜  ~ resolvectl --version
systemd 251 (251.10-588.fc37)
```

[image: systemd-resolved status]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after I enabled the debug flag for `systemd` logs. I followed answer specified here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432077/556205.

After setting the flag, I was able to see a concrete error message: `libsystemd-shared-251.8-586.fc37.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I then ran `ls /usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-*` and found that the file does not exist. Instead, another file of different version was there: `/usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-251.10-588.fc37.so`. This was possibly due to the recent update that I did.

I don't think it's a good practice, but as a fix I linked the two files: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-251.10-588.fc37.so /usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-251.8-586.fc37.so`. Everything started to work after this!